# How can we concatenate two columns based on names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I was working with a multiindex dataframe (which I find unbeleivably complicated to work with).  I flattened the multiindex into jest Level0, with this line of code.

```
df_append.columns = df_append.columns.map('|'.join).str.strip('|')
```

Now, when I print columns, I get this.

```
Index(['IDRSSD', 'RCFD3531|TRDG ASSETS-US TREAS SECS IN DOM OFF',
       'RCFD3532|TRDG ASSETS-US GOV AGC CORP OBLGS',
       'RCFD3533|TRDG ASSETS-SECS ISSD BY ST  POL SUB',
       'TEXTF660|3RD ITEMIZED AMT FOR OTHR TRDG ASTS',
       'Unnamed: 115_level_0|Unnamed: 115_level_1',
       'Unnamed: 133_level_0|Unnamed: 133_level_1',
       'Unnamed: 139_level_0|Unnamed: 139_level_1',
       'Unnamed: 20_level_0|Unnamed: 20_level_1',
       'Unnamed: 87_level_0|Unnamed: 87_level_1', 'file', 'schedule_code',
       'year', 'qyear'],
      dtype='object', length=202)
```

I am trying to concatenate two columns into one single column, like this.

```
df_append['period'] = df_append['IDRSSD'].astype(str) + '-' + df_append['qyear'].astype(str)
```

Here is the error that I am seeing.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2895, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'IDRSSD'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-153-92d2e8486595>", line 1, in <module>
    df_append['period'] = df_append['IDRSSD'].astype(str) + '-' + df_append['qyear'].astype(str)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 'IDRSSD'
```

To me, it looks like I have a column named 'IDRSSD' and a column named 'qyear', but Python disagrees.  Or, perhaps I am misinterpreting the error message.  Can I get these two columns concatenated into one, or is this impossible to do?  Thanks everyone.

Comment: can you please check you have the columns using `print(df_append.columns)` there may be whitespaces before or after string

Comment: What is the pandas version you are using?

Comment: The issue doesn't seem reproducible at my end, tried a bunch of variations with multi-indexes to see the cause of the error. I can only recommend 1. check if some intermediate code isn't setting 'IDRSSD' to an index instead of column, 2. Check the 202 length column index to ensure there isnt any other issue causing it (duplicate col names due to the concatenation of multi-indexes)\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the method below. It worked for me.

1.) First convert the column to string:

```
df_append['IDRSSD'] = df_append['IDRSSD'].astype(str)
df_append['qyear'] = df_append['qyear'].astype(str)
```

2.) Now join then both the columns into one using '-' as seperator

```
df_append['period'] = df_append[['IDRSSD', 'qyear']].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x), axis=1)
```

Attached the screenshot of my approach.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

use apply method

```
import pandas as pd
def concat(row):
    if ("col1" in row) & ("col2" in row):
        return str(row['col1']) + "-" +str(row['col2'])
df =pd.DataFrame([["1","2"],["1","2"]],columns=["col1","col2"])
df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda row: concat(row), axis=1)
df
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df_append.columns = df_append.columns.to_flat_index()` to change the MultiIndex into a one dimensional array of tuples. From there you should be able to manipulate the columns more easily, or at least see what the issue is.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_flat_index.html